# Google Script Get ID Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Can anyone help me? I am trying to get the folder ID of a specific sub-folder. I keep getting getID invalid function.

Basically the aim is to add the file uploaded to the relevant folder based on what has been selected on the form.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "1AoOkQPyEp23NCeYo1RFsjGpekCXecyZGN2woTvelIvMs3DwbgKomUm0DUwoM1-R5g1fadyW_"  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder where all schools are stored
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  // Gets the selected school
  var schoolName=itemResponses[1].getResponse();

  var subFoldName = destFolder.getFoldersByName(schoolName);

  var selectedFolderID = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(subFoldName).getID();

  // Move files to the folder.
 
  Logger.log(destFolder);
  Logger.log (schoolName);
  Logger.log(subFoldName);
  Logger.log(selectedFolderID);

  DriveApp.getFolderById(folder).addFile(id);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [`getFoldersByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename) gets you [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator), not a single folder hence the error "getID invalid".

To get a single Folder use [`getFoldersByName().next()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator#next) if you are certain there is only one folder with that name.